# Dapper procedure returns nothing after refresh

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, dapper

I've got a huge problem. I use dapper as micro orm in my project and when I make a query with stored procedure in package IT WORKS (but only the first time, **after second and third the same query, same parameters and same execution returns nothing**). After while, that query works again, but still only for one time same as before.

But when I do the same query from database (in sqldeveloper) it always works
So I claim that a problem is connected with dapper. I guess.

I have no idea how to fix this. I have changed that procedure to a function but effect is still the same. I work on OracleDb, in asp MVC ofc.

The execution of procedure is :

```
var Parm = new OracleDynamicParameters();
Parm.Add("refCur", OracleDbType.RefCursor, ParameterDirection.Output);
Parm.Add(name: "ID", value: id, direction: ParameterDirection.Input);
return con.Query<SAMPLE_MODEL>("SAMPLE_PACKAGE.SAMPLE_PROC", Parm, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure).ToList();
```

Comment: Hello. Updated news.

I switched my query with procedure on ADO DB. And it also dosen't worked so the problem is undefined i guess. I also had idea that there is something wrong with procedure. I used there DBlinks. 
Is there any option to block dblinks for using them from c#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check that every session got a unit id.  Every query which uses a dblink requires a new session id with the database.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I Just added `pooling=false` im my web.config.